# Item_name missing with 'hosted-payment' payment system

Tags: php, paypal

i have an issue with paypal payment.

The website is www.produzioneintegratori.it and we use the _hosted-payment system i.imgur.com/MHFJkJq.png

The code is:

```
<iframe style="display:none" id="hss_iframe" name="hss_iframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="540px"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
    <input type="hidden" id="subtotalpaypal" name="subtotal" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo OUR_DOMAIN . '/shop/fineacquisto.php?f=paypal'; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo OUR_DOMAIN . '/shop/carrello.php'; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="<?php echo OUR_DOMAIN . '/img/logointegratori.jpg'; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo URL_PAYPAL_IPN_CC; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value="Pagamento prodotti <?php echo $id_carrello_trovato_top; ?>BIOLINE">
    <input type="hidden" id="custompaypal" name="custompaypal" value="Pagamento prodotti <?php echo $id_carrello_trovato_top; ?>BIOLINE">
    <input type="hidden" id="buyer_email" name="buyer_email" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pagamento prodotti <?php echo $id_carrello_trovato_top; ?>BIOLINE">
</form>
```

we have only 1 item_name per cart: for eg 'Pagamento prodotti XXXXXBIOLINE'.

the customers can pay with:

1. "Pay with my credit or debit card". Everiting is fine and we receive back the correct IPN and an email from paypal with item_name i.imgur.com/lLTpiVn.png
2. "Pay with my PayPal account". Here we have a problem because we receive the correct IPN without item_name and an email without item_name i.imgur.com/VCa4tRv.png

For us it's importart to receive the 'item_name' also if the clients pay with their paypal accounts.

If you click on "Pay with Paypal" you clearly see the item_name it's not passed and it's missing i.imgur.com/QZhLHEW.png

Do you have any solutions?

thanks in advance

Comment: It may be due to wrong string concatenation.Try `<?php echo "Pagamento prodotti".$id_carrello_trovato_top."BIOLINE"; ?>`

Comment: no. It's not this. Thank you

Comment: it's a ["Paypal Pro" value](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf)

Comment: Have you fixed the problem?

Comment: unfortunately no ...

Comment: @Gunaseelan i just spoke with a tech paypal. The 'item_name' it's not supported on paypal pro. I'll try to use IPN to verify and send the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Pro Hosted does not support the variable **item_name**

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that please?

Comment: No reference needed, it's simply not documented